# how to write query in this particular situation?

Tags: mysql

```
id     userid         note       created_date

1       100             x        2010-09-29 02:24:57
2       101             y        some date
3       100             z        some date
4       103             a           "
5       100             b           "
6       102             c           "
```

I want to latest `2 result` of `userid` `100 and 102`. This is the situation to understand the problem. Actually I have a list of userid and I want the latest `n result` of `userid` which is in my `list of userid`.

Comment: You should try and re-phrase this question as it's very hard/impossible to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was very difficult to understand but I'll give you three possible answers:

1) If you want the results by the highest user iD ("latest" could mean that), you should do

```
select * from table
order by userId desc
limit 0, 2
```

2) If you want them ordered by creation date (which "latest" could also mean), type

```
select * from table
order by created_date desc
limit 0, 2
```

3) if your "list of userid" is another table, you want to join it

```
select t.* from table t
inner join list_of_userid u
on u.userid = t.userid
order by created_date desc
limit 0, 2
```

If you actually want something else, you'll have to explain it :)

Comment: +1 But that leaves us mighty curious as to *what* query ended up being *the one*.